# Calling an optional JS fetch promise from multiple code locations

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, es6-promise

I have three URLs I need to access in my code. The first two will always be accessed, but the third one might be accessed zero, one or two times. As all URLs take a lot of processing, I don't want to access the third one if I don't have to.

My code is something like this:

```js
fetch('a')
.then(response => response.json() }
.then(data => {
  if (data.value == '1') {
    fetch('c')
    .then(response => response.json() }
    .then(data => console.log('through a', data));
  }
}
fetch('b')
.then(response => response.json() }
.then(data => {
  if (data.value == '1') {
    fetch('c')
    .then(response => response.json() }
    .then(data => console.log('through a', data));
  }
}
```

So, the result from URL 'c' might be needed zero, one or two times. Both a, b and c can take a while to process, so either 'a' or 'b' might be first accessing 'c'. In case both need to return 'c', I don't want a second fetch to be performed, I want the second one to return the value already fetched by the first one.

My thought was to do it like this:

```js
const c = () => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    fetch('c')
    .then(response => response.json() };
  })
}

fetch('a')
.then(response => response.json() }
.then(data => {
  if (data.value == '1') {
    c().then(data => console.log('through a', data));
  }
}
fetch('b')
.then(response => response.json() }
.then(data => {
  if (data.value == '1') {
    c().then(data => console.log('through b', data));
  }
}
```

But this still causes 'c' to be accessed twice if both 'a' and 'b' return '1'.

How should I do this instead?

Comment: `const c = () => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    fetch('c');
  })
}` will never resolve

Comment: @JaromandaX it does in my code?

Comment: I bet it doesn't, considering the `new Promise` you create doesn't even take any arguments (e.g. resolve, reject) which are the only way to settle a `new Promise`

Comment: Of course, "your code" may not be the code you posted

Comment: a generic *term* you may want to research for this type of code is *memoize*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to lazily call *"c"* and at most once.

Something like this should suffice

```js
let cPromise;

const c = () => (cPromise ??= fetch("c").then((r) => r.json()));

fetch("a")
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then(({ value }) => {
    if (value === "1") {
      c().then((data) => {
        console.log("through a", data);
      });
    }
  });

fetch("b")
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then(({ value }) => {
    if (value === "1") {
      c().then((data) => {
        console.log("through a", data);
      });
    }
  });
```

The [Nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) means `cPromise` will only be assigned once when `c()` is first called. It also means `fetch("c")` will only be called at most one time.

Comment: This looks very smart! At some place in my code I also need to run fetches in a loop, this looks like a great way to solve it! One question; if a second call to c() is make while the first is still waiting for a response, is a second fetch then performed?

Comment: @Peter no, the fetch will be made only once.

Comment: @Peter No, because this isn't setting `cPromise` to the response. It's setting it to the Promise that's returned as soon as you send the request.

Comment: Was about to post similar ... only difference is I would make `c` *"self contained"* - `const c = (() => { let result; return () => result ??= fetch('c').then(r=>r.json()); })();` - just a thought :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd just put it in its own module, making `cPromise` opaque

Comment: @Phil - yes, that of course is a good option - I'm always too worried about "global" pollution (and I don't mean just the oceans :p)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Promise.all()` to check the result of both fetches, then fetch from `c` if either of them returns the value 1.

```
Promise.all([
    fetch('a').then(res => res.text()), 
    fetch('b').then(res => res.text())
]).then((result1, result2) => {
    if (result1 == "1" || result2 == "1") {
        fetch('c').then(...)
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I never really grasped Promise.all, I am going to try this out!

Answer (score 0):

The last time I experimented with this, I think what I observed is that if one `fetch('c')` is already pending but doesn't have a response yet, then a second call to `fetch('c')` will not use the browser cache and instead start a second request (maybe do some experiments to see if this is correct). In this case, you can manually cache the `c` request by storing the promise like `let cPromise = null` and replacing all `fetch('c').then()` with:

```js
if (!cPromise) {
  cPromise = fetch('c')
}
cPromise.then(...)
```

This can be nice if you'll eventually need to do this for a bunch of different urls that could be saved in a Map. Keep in mind with this solution you'll make one `'c'` request, but both `cPromise.then()`'s will execute, so only do this if that's your desired behavior.